# How to loop through JSON objects of my json file inside the response of my http trigger function?

Tags: python, json, azure-functions

I am trying to parse an array of JSON and return them.

I saw that I could use something like this outside of an HttpTrigger function in Python

`response['Body'] = [json.loads(item['Body']['bytes']) for item in response]`

I would like to do this in my HTTP trigger function

I imagined something like this:

```
with open('json_file.json','rb') as file:
               jsonStr = file.read()
               
return func.HttpResponse(json.loads(jsonStr)['Body']['bytes'] for jsonStr item in func.HttpResponse, status_code=200)
```

Where json_file.json is a file with the following content.

json_file.json

```
[
  {"id":1,"receiver":"77777777","message":{"test":" test signal","VehId":3,"DriverId":2,"GUID":"1s3q1d-s546dq1-8e22e","LineId":2,"SvcId":2,"Lat":-64.546547,"Lon":-68.546547,"TimeStamp":"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z","Recorder":"dq65ds4qdezzer","Env":"PRD"},"operator":20404,"sender":"MSISDN","binary":1,"sent":"2021-03-29T08:29:36.758Z"},
  {"id":1,"receiver":"77777777","message":{"test":" test signal","VehId":3,"DriverId":2,"GUID":"1s3q1d-s546dq1-8e22e","LineId":2,"SvcId":2,"Lat":-64.546547,"Lon":-68.546547,"TimeStamp":"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z","Recorder":"dq65ds4qdezzer","Env":"PRD"},"operator":20404,"sender":"MSISDN","binary":1,"sent":"2021-03-29T08:29:36.758Z"},
  {"id":1,"receiver":"77777777","message":{"test":" test signal","VehId":3,"DriverId":2,"GUID":"1s3q1d-s546dq1-8e22e","LineId":2,"SvcId":2,"Lat":-64.546547,"Lon":-68.546547,"TimeStamp":"2021-03-18T08:29:36.758Z","Recorder":"dq65ds4qdezzer","Env":"PRD"},"operator":20404,"sender":"MSISDN","binary":1,"sent":"2021-03-29T08:29:36.758Z"}
]
```

I know the return will not work with the "func.HttpResponse", but I can't figure out how to loop through all the JSON objects in my file using an HTTP trigger function in Python.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
with open('json_file.json','rb') as file:
               test = file.readlines()
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('json_file.json'))
jsonarr = []
print(num_lines)
for x in range(1,num_lines-1):
    if x!=3:
        #print(test[x].decode('utf8')[:-3])
        data = json.loads(test[x].decode('utf8')[:-3])
        jsonarr.append(data)
    else:
        #print(test[x].decode('utf8'))
        data = json.loads(test[x].decode('utf8'))
        jsonarr.append(data)

for json in jsonarr:
    item = json["id"]
    print(item)
```